# Stripe Form Error The 'exp_month' parameter should be an integer (instead, is undefined) and custom form questions

Tags: forms, stripe-payments

First off, I'm a newbie in all this so forgive me if I may have to ask a lot of questions.

I'm working on a Stripe Payment form. I basically copied and pasted the sample code, changing some entries based on how I understood it. I have several concerns/questions:

1. The error **"The 'exp_month' parameter should be an integer (instead, is undefined)**. I checked my code and made sure that I followed the suggested solution to others' issue similar to this error. I believe I have everything in order but I'm still getting the issue.
2. Before this issue, I was able to submit transactions in testing environment but I'm not seeing them on the log section of Stripe's Dashboard. Is there anything missing on my codes?
3. I need help in being able to capture name, address, phone number, email address. I added entry fields on the form, but the data are not recorded. Please help me on this as well.

I'm sharing the codes I'm currently using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Purchase 1-On-1 Private Photography Course</title>

  <!-- The required Stripe lib -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

  <!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('Stripe Test Publishable Key');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, name, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
Stripe.card.createToken({
    name: $('.customer-name').val(),
    address_line1: $('.address- line1').val(),
    address_line2: $('.address-line2').val(),
    address_city: $('.city-address').val(),
    address_state: $('.state-address').val(),
    address_zip: $('.address-zip').val(),
    email: $('.customer-email').val(),
    phone_number: $('.phone-number').val(),
    number: $('.card-number').val(),
    cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
    exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
    exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
}, 
stripeResponseHandler);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Purchase 1-On-1 Private Photography Course</h1>

  <form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input type="text" size="30" data-stripe="name"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Address Line 1</span>
        <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="address_line1"/>
      </label>
      <label>
         <span>Address Line 2</span>
        <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="address_line2"/>
     </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>City</span>
        <input type="text" size="15" data-stripe="address_city"/>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>State</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="address_state"/>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Zip</span>
        <input type="text" size="5" data-stripe="address_zip"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Email</span>
        <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="email"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Phone Number</span>
        <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="phone_number"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Card Number</span>
        <input type="number" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>CVC</span>
        <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
        <input type="number" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month"/>
      </label>
      <span> / </span>
      <input type="number" size="4" data-stripe="exp_year"/>
    </div>

  <h2>Upon submitting your payment, you will be charged AUD20.00</h2> 

    <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have combined incompatible code from old tutorials and new tutorials, but it's easy enough to fix!

All the `val()` calls you're passing to `createToken` will return an undefined value. You're using class accessors (i.e. looking for a DOM element with class of `address-line1`), but none of your form fields have a class attribute; they're using data attributes.

You'll instead want to look the fields up via their `data-stripe` attribute:

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
  name: $('input[data-stripe=name]').val(),
  address_line1: $('input[data-stripe=address-line1]').val(),
  // etc.
```

While you're making this change, also double-check that you're using the same `data-stripe` value in both the form and the jQuery selector—right now there are several places where the two don't match. For example, the form uses `address_line1` while your jQuery looks for `address-line1`.